# MatLab handle graphics - zooming with two y-axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to plot two different quantities, voltage and current, on a single figure (or same axes space, if we want to be technical).  I tried using `plotyy` but it leaves errant tick marks on the right side when I manually set limits/ticks, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094827/double-axis-used-in-matlab).  After becoming well versed in handle graphics over the past year, I figure there has to be a way to take matters into my own hands.  Here is what I've tried:

```
% Voltage axes setup
axHandle(1) = ...
    axes('XLim',[0,24],'XTick',0:24,'YLim',[0, 18],'YTick',0:18, ...
    'Parent', figHandle(1));
xlabel(axHandle(1),'Time [local-military]')
ylabel(axHandle(1),'Voltage [volts]')
hold(axHandle(1),'on')

% Current axes setup
axHandle(2) = ...
    axes('YAxisLocation','right', 'Color','none', ...
    'XLim',[0,24],'XTick',[],'YLim',[0 1.7],'YTick',0:0.1:1.7, ...
    'Parent', figHandle(1));
ylabel(axHandle(2),'Current [amps]')
hold(axHandle(2),'on')

% Plot data
voltPlotHandle = plot(axHandle(1), timeVec, voltVec, 'b.');
currPlotHandle = plot(axHandle(2), timeVec, currVec, 'r.');
```

While the results looks pretty at first glance, when I go to use the zoom tool I encounter a problem: only the second axes is active, therefore the voltage graph remains unmagnified.

Whatever `plotyy` is doing in the background, it doesn't have this problem.  Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`linking the axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html), so they share the same limits on pan/zoom.

```
linkaxes([axHandle(1) axHandle(2)],'xy');
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought his worked at first, but this actually makes the limits of both axes (left and right) the same.  I'm looking to maintain different limits on each axes.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Don't worry. Just remove the `y` from the code above. In this case you want to link only the axis they have in common which is the x axis (time). If it works I'll update the answer accordingly